# early binding late binding is it same as runtime and compile time?

Tags: java

When we create object inside a function is that object created at runtime?

What are the things happen? created? at compile time and at runtime?

Is early binding and late binding also means compile time and runtime?
What is dynamic linking static linking? is it right to think compile time when I hear static? damn I so confused?

sorry guys I know my english is bad and also please make your answers and examples beginner friendly as possible.

Comment: Yes, objects are instantiated at runtime. I wasn't aware there was even a concept of "static linking" in Java. I can't really understand the rest of the question.

Comment: actually i just heard about this static linking and dynamic linking linking I dont know those thing thats why Im asking.

Comment: Those terms are usually used to refer to assembled machine code, e.g. you can statically link in a C++ library or dynamically link the dll file. In Java there isn't really an exact analog, as everything is loaded with the same kind of classloader.

Answer (score 1):

Early binding is like going getting tomatoes from the refridgerator and putting them on the table before you starting cooking the soup.

Late binding is starting cooking the soup, and when you need tomatoes, then you go to get them from the refridgerator.

Cooking the soup is run time.

Getting the knife,spoon and saucepan ready is compile time. (It doesn't involve tomatoes.)

---

Ok here's a pseudo coded explanation :

**late binding :**

```
... get : 
if (myvar is null) myvar = new object;
return myvar
```

**early binding**

```
myvar = new object;
... get :
return myvar
```

Comment: ObjectClass obj = new ObjectClass();

Comment: ObjectClass obj = new ObjectClass(); //whats early binding here, whats late binding here?

Comment: ObjectClass is your tomato (it is ready), and you're getting one of them to the table. It's an early binding. But if you are using it inside an event or condition, if something must occur before this could be created, it's late binding.

Comment: what you mean inside an event or condition?

Comment: I've explained it inside my answer.

Comment: http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/dynamic-binding-vs-static-binding-in.html

Comment: @Igor Nikolaev <- I thought all Object are all dynamically instantiated( or maybe I mean created).

Comment: When the type of object is determined during runtime. Like you have an interface and call it's methods everywhere. But interface cannot be instantiated so you provide an implementation. But during compile-time compiler doesn't know which exactly implementation will be used.

Answer (score 0):

> When we create object inside a function is that object created at
>   runtime?
>
> What are the things happen? created? at compile time and at runtime?

That depends on what you mean by "object." If you mean a class instance, then yes it will be created at runtime on either the stack or the heap. [Statically allocated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) objects, like strings or types explicitly declared as static, will be created at compile-time in the [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment). Static variables live for the life of the program.

> Is early binding and late binding also means compile time and runtime?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_binding):

> With early binding the compiler statically verifies that there are one
>   or more methods with the appropriate method name and signature. This
>   is usually stored in the compiled program as an offset in a virtual
>   method table ("v-table") and is very efficient. With late binding the
>   compiler does not have enough information to verify the method even
>   exists, let alone bind to its particular slot on the v-table. Instead
>   the method is looked up by name at runtime.

In a nutshell, in early binding the compiler looks up the method and its offset in the symbol table, so that information must be available, whereas in late binding that can't be done, and the runtime must look it up. Note that late binding is very different from dynamic dispatch, though they are often used synonymously, in that the latter refers to using a dispatch table or "vtable" to store pointers to a method's implementation, which may be overridden.

> What is dynamic linking static linking?

Basically this is difference between including referenced files or "libraries" in the final executable (static) and placing them into the program image at runtime. Obviously, the former adds unnecessary size to the executable, but (1) you never have to worry about dependency issues and (2) program start up is more efficient. On the other hand, dynamic linking (1) saves spaces and (2) allows library updates to occur in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in Java is statically **linked**, but it is statically **bound**. "Static" means the compiler identifies the exact description of the function to be called: class name, method name, argument types. It does NOT determine its address in memory. That's the difference between static binding and static linking, and this means that it is still not known at compile time what code will be executed when you call a static method. It depends on what's in the .class file that the JVM loads at runtime. Java statically binds all calls to `static` methods -- hence the keyword. It also applies static binding to `private` methods, since they cannot be overridden. A similar argument applies to `final` methods.

Dynamic binding means that the compiler decides everything like in the static case, **except** for the class which contains that method. The exact class is determined at the last moment before calling the method, relative to the object on which the method is being called. `Object.equals` is such a dynamically bound method. This means that the **same** line of code can call a **different** method each time it is executed.

Early binding == static binding; late binding == dynamic binding. These are synonyms.

Comment: "Static" means different things in different contexts, and there are a few of them (typing, visibility, link & load, allocation). And late binding != dynamic binding: "Late binding is often confused with dynamic dispatch, but there are significant differences." ~ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding (2nd paragraph)

Comment: Are you talking about Java or programming languages in general? I wasn't trying to give OP a lecture in CS.

Answer (score 0):

early binding is a assignment of value to design time where a late binding is a assignment of value to runtime
There is only difference between run time and design time it must show the value of assignment .
For example:

```
//early binding 
myvar =new myvar();
// get
retutn myvar
```